# How to refine a linear FEM mesh in three regions?

Tags: regions, finite-element-method, mesh

I am trying to solve the one-dimensional wave equation with a frequency dependent source function over three intervals with varying velocity. I need to refine the mesh over the low velocity regions when the wavelength becomes shorter. The documentation for DiscretizeRegion shows how to do this for the left half of a linear region using step functions, but this MeshRefinementFunction does not work for ToElementMesh.

```
DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Line[{{0}, {1.8}}], Line[{{1.8}, {2.2}}], 
Line[{{2.2}, {4}}]], MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{v, Len}, If[Max[v] 
>= 2, Len > 0.003, Len > 0.5]]]
```

Can you help?

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
ToElementMesh[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[Line[{{0}, {1.8}}], Line[{{1.8}, {2.2}}], 
   Line[{{2.2}, {4}}]], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{v, Len}, If[Max[v] >= 2, Len > 0.003, Len > 0.5]]]]
```

Another approach you could take is to create a boundary mesh and then use RegionMarkers:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0}, {1.8}, {2.2}, {4}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {1, 1, 3,
        3}]}, "PointElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, \
{1, 1, 3, 3}]}];

m = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.9}, 1, 0.01}, {{2}, 2, 0.1}, {{3}, 3, 0.001}}]
m["Wireframe"]
```

See the [ToElementMesh ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) or the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Also note that there are two tutorials that might be of interest: one is on the [wave equation in acoustics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html) and one on the [Helmholtz equation for the frequency domain in Acoustics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsFrequencyDomain.html#1527648872). The fact that the tutorials are about Acoustics is not that important since many things are still applicable. Also, have a look for the acoustics models in product with examples.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I used the boundary mesh approach with this code:

```
    bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0}, {1.9}, {2.1}, {4}}, 
    "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {1, 1, 3, 3}]}, 
    "PointElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {1, 1, 3, 3}]}];

    m2 = ToElementMesh[bmesh,"RegionMarker" -> {{{0.9}, 1, 0.2}, {{2}, 2, 0.05}, 
    {{3}, 3, 0.1}}]
```

Then I used NDSolve and got a much better result for the frequency range I was using